# can i use divs as long as the html5 validation is ok

Tags: html

As long as the html5 validation is ok [using w3](http://validator.w3.org/)

then the html5 can be published and be ok.
or is there some kind of check list i should be looking at ?

Comment: How is this programming-related?

Comment: Of course you can use divs, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Avoiding `<div>`s is a code style issue, not a technical requirement.

Answer (score 3):

If your just talking about getting HTML5 elements to work you will want to add the HTML5shiv so that the elements are recognized in all browsers.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Yea i saw people doing that, and i get that. but ok this is whats bugging me.

Comment: I want to make a message system (PM), using html5 i dont want to use a table. i want to use just divs. would that be ok ?

Comment: Yes you can still use divs in html5.